# Value error: could not convert str to float PYTHON

Tags: python

Here is my code. I don't get why I get this error and how to correct it.
The error appears at: `totals = entrant + float(tot)`
here is my full code:

```
def total():
    File = open("argent.txt","r")
    File = File.read()
    tot = File
    print("You have",tot,"Â£ in your account")

def add():
    entrant = float(input("How many do you want to add to your account? "))

    with open("argent.txt", 'r') as f:
        tot = f.read().rstrip('\n')

    print("You have ",tot,"Â£ in your account")
    totals = entrant + float(tot)
    print(totals)

    with open("argent.txt", 'w') as f:
        output = str(totals)
        f.write(output)
add()
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `tot` is not a valid float

Comment: Provide a sample of your file content or the `print` statement above

Comment: the file is just a text file with 20 in the first line.

Comment: does your file have only one line?

Comment: yes my file have only one line with 20 in it. i don't know how to provide a sample.

Comment: Check the character encoding of your text file.

Comment: @GermainLeignel I copied your code directly into IDLE and ran it. The code runs just fine. No "ValueError". Try your code in IDLE.  You also have a function `total()` that you don't use anywhere.

Comment: The only logical explanation I could give right now is that your text file encoding is something that Python can't decode. So, you could find that encoding and change it to UTF-8 or you could properly tell Python to decode your encoding if you don't want to change it.

Answer (score 0):

In your case the function `read()` read not only characters `20` but also a new line character(s) appended to it.

So the variable `tot` contains the value which is not convertible to a number.

Try

```
tot = tot.strip()
```

before using it.

Answer (score 0):

In the future, try avoid using `File` for `file type` variables.

```
entrant = float(input("How many do you want to add to your account? "))

with open("argent.txt", 'r') as f:
    tot = f.read().rstrip('\n')

print("You have ",tot,"£ in your account")
totals = entrant + float(tot)
print(totals)

with open("argent.txt", 'w') as f:
    output = str(totals)
    f.write(output)
```

By using `with open` the file is close after the following code.

**Edit:** Fixed the `'w'` to file output from `float` to `str`

Comment: i get "ValueError: could not convert string to float:" for totals = entrant + float(tot)

Comment: @GermainLeignel This was tested with Python 3.6 on a `.txt` with only the number `20` in it. What are you running this against? Are you on Windows or *nix?

Comment: @GermainLeignel It sounds like we need to look at the contents of your file.

Comment: I am on 3.3.6 using pyscripter and windows 10 would it change anything?

Comment: @GermainLeignel It shouldn't. Again though, in order to help we need to see the contents of your file and your Python script exactly as it is written. I recommend you update your original post with the script as you have it currently written and show us the contents of your file.